# Is there a framework available which could help me in testing DAOs

Tags: cassandra, playframework-2.6

My `Scala` `Play` application uses cassandra database. I want to unit-test the DAO classes. I have created but I don't know if there is a framework which is specifically built for this. Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say about DAO classes in Play framework, but usually you can use either [embedded-cassandra](https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra) or [cassandra-unit](https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit) for unit testing of applications that are working with Cassandra.

Comment: Alex - I am following the `ccm` approach (https://github.com/riptano/ccm/blob/master/README.md). While I have been able to manually create the cluster, I am clueless how to do it programatically. I have opened a new issue. Could you please take a look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56138151/how-to-use-ccmlib-in-scala-play-application

Comment: Just to keep you updated, I have abandoned `ccm` approach for now due to issues I am facing in starting and stopping ccm from my unit tests. I am trying embedded-cassandra approach and have already stumbled upon my first issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161409/how-to-import-a-maven-dependency-using-sbt