# how to use ccmlib in scala/play application

Tags: ccm

My `scala`/`play` application uses `cassandra` database. I want to unit-test the database services. I believe I can use `ccm` tool to create a cluster locally. I am able to do so following the instruction at https://github.com/riptano/ccm/blob/master/README.md

But I can't figure out how to start, stop and populate the cluster programatically in the unit test (`Playspec`).

Comment: have you tried to execute the same commands from your Scala code? in the Setup phase of the unit test...

Comment: yes, please see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142538/unable-to-start-a-process-in-scala-play-application