# unable to start a Process in Scala/Play application

Tags: scala, automated-tests, playframework-2.6

I have a `ccm.py` script which runs `Cassandra` cluster on local machine. I am able to run the command using windows command prompt. But I get error if I try to do so using `Process` class in `Scala`.

I want to run it before starting my test cases. So I am calling `Process` in `beforeAll`.

```
override def beforeAll():Unit = {
    println("starting cassandra cluster locally")
    val ccmCommand = Process("ccm.py start").!
  }
```

The error I get is

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Cannot run program "ccm.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ccm.py": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

I also tried using `cassandra -f` command (which also works from `cmd` prompt) but  I got error

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Cannot run program "cassandra": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cassandra": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

How can I solve the issue?

Update
Thanks to Alex Ott, I have made some progress but I think there has to be a better and more reliable way to test the code and also make the code more portable

The code which seem to work so far is

```
override def beforeAll():Unit = {
    println("starting cassandra cluster locally")
      val ccmCommand = Process("python",Seq("C:\\Users\\manu\\Documents\\manu\\ccm-3.1.4.tar\\dist\\ccm-3.1.4\\ccm.py","start")).run //NOT GOOD. Using hardcoded path!!

    println(s"ccm returned ${ccmCommand}")
    Thread.sleep(30000) //the wait is too long and there is no guarantee that the cluster will be up properly
  }
```

Is there a better (w.r.t reliable without hard coding the path) to bring up the cluster before tests get executed.

Comment: have you tried to run it as `python ccm.py ...` ?

Comment: tried `val ccmCommand = Process("python ccm.py",Seq("start")).!`.It didn't work. Tried `val ccmCommand = Process("python",Seq("ccm.py","start")).!`. I got error `python: can't open file 'ccm.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. So I did `val ccmCommand = Process("python",Seq("C:\\Users\\manu\\Documents\\manu\\ccm-3.1.4.tar\\dist\\ccm-3.1.4\\ccm.py","start")).!` which starts the cluster but it isn't returning and thus my test is stuck.  I tried using `run` instead of `!` but that returns immediately. My test case runs but only 1 node is up at that time. I have updated the question.

Comment: unfortunately I can't help with windows, and starting processes there...