# how to import a Maven dependency using SBT

Tags: maven, sbt

I am trying to get `embedded-cassandra` in my `scala/play` project which uses `sbt` instead of maven. (https://github.com/nosan/embedded-cassandra/wiki)

I translated the following maven dependency into sbt.

```
<!-- Core API -->
     <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.nosan</groupId>
          <artifactId>embedded-cassandra</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Extensions (Spring, JUnit, etc.) -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.github.nosan</groupId>
         <artifactId>embedded-cassandra-test</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
```

SBT conversion

```
"com.github.nosan"%"embedded-cassandra" % "2.0.1" % "test"
```

But I am getting compilation error when I try to import embedded-cassandra in my unit test.

`import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Cassandra`

error

```
Error:(7, 12) object github is not a member of package com
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Cassandra
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the issue was that `SBT` hadn't downloaded the dependency. I re-imported the project and things worked. I made another change. I removed the `% test` from the sbt entry though to be honest I don't know if that had any implications.